# How to redirect the nslog output to file instead of console

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, nslog

I have cocoa application running on OS X. I have used NSLog for debugging purpose. Now I want to redirect the log statements to file instead of console.

I have used this method but it results logging in Console as well as in file.

```
- (BOOL)redirectNSLog
{
    // Create log file
    [@"" writeToFile:@"/NSLog.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    id fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:@"/NSLog.txt"];
    if (!fileHandle)    return NSLog(@"Opening log failed"), NO;
    [fileHandle retain];

    // Redirect stderr
    int err = dup2([fileHandle fileDescriptor], STDERR_FILENO);
    if (!err)   return  NSLog(@"Couldn't redirect stderr"), NO;

    return  YES;
}
```

Is it possible to not have log statement in console but only in file ??

Answer (score -9, accepted):

`NSLog` is made to log into the console.  You need to define your own function `MyLog` or whatever, and replace all occurrences of `NSLog` into `MyLog`.

Comment: I did define my function and replace NSLog with my defined function. But still I do see logs in Cosole application as well as in log file which I created. I liked the idea of defining own function for logging.

Comment: Confirm that the file creation worked. I have tested this code and it works. The linked code writes the file to root which I changed to my local home directory.

Answer (score 72):

Step 1: Include following function in AppDelegate:

```
 - (void) redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder
 {
       NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
       NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
       NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console.log"];
       freopen([logPath fileSystemRepresentation],"a+",stderr);
 }
```

Step 2: Call this function at the start of function applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions...

Thats it, Every NSLog() will now get redirected to this console.log file, which you can find in the documents directory.

Comment: Definitely a better answer than mine:) Changed `cStringWithEncoding:NSASCII...` to `fileSystemRepresentation`. People can have non-ASCII letters in the path (which is unlikely on `~/Documents/`)

Comment: Wonderful! It also works for iOS apps. You will find the console.log inside a directory like this: `/Users/Fernando/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/18FB521C-A782-44E4-9DFA-B963FD7DC44B/Documents/console.log` Thanks! :-)

Comment: To close/stop writing output in console - use `fflush(fileP); fclose(fileP);` To get file pointer, use `FILE *fileP = freopen([logPath..` in above method and keep this pointer around. This way you can wrap around specific flow/nslog calls to this output file.

Comment: Also, if you don't see the whole output (some part is missing) you can add a function `void flush_std_err() { fflush(stderr); }` and hook on `at_exit` somewhere in main `at_exit(flush_std_err)`

Comment: Could you explain why the stream is from stderr

Comment: why using stderr instead of stdout in freopen?

Answer (score 12):

Recently i have faced similar requirement and this is how i have done it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    [self redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder];


    return YES;
}

- (void) redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console.txt"];
    freopen([logPath fileSystemRepresentation],"a+",stderr);
}
```

And Now if you want to this console to user

```
-(void)displayLog{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths firstObject];
    NSString *logPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"console.txt"];

    NSError *err = nil;
    NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:logPath
                                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                          error:&err];
    if (fileContents == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading %@: %@", logPath, err);
    } else {
        self.textView.text = fileContents;
    }

}
```

Comment: just what i needed for a quick bout of debugging :-)

Comment: You can use  `tail –f console.log` runtime see the log, or use `tail –f console.log | grep “xxx”`

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack#readme).  It is a very flexible logging framework for both Mac OS X and iOS.  One logging statement can be sent not only to the console but to a file simultaneously.  Plus it is actually faster then NSLog.  I use it in a project that has common code for both OS X and iOS.

Comment: Thanks dbainbridge. I am using the same framework for my apps.

Comment: Does CocoaLumberjack redirect NSLog? I searched it's code base no sign of freopen.I guess not.

Comment: It would be better to replace your NSLogs with the proper DDLog* statements with CocoaLumberjack.  CocoaLumberjack also uses GCD so it is much faster then simply replacing NSLog with a different method.