# How to get the console logs and display in a textview [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

How can I get the console logs with all the print/Nslog contents and display it on a textview? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: "How can I get the console logs" You can't. If you could, there would be apps that display the console logs, and there are no such apps nowadays.

Answer (score 3):

To accomplish this I modified the `OutputListener` Class described in this article titled "[Intercepting stdout in Swift](https://phatbl.at/2019/01/08/intercepting-stdout-in-swift.html)" by phatblat:

```
func captureStandardOutputAndRouteToTextView() {
    outputPipe = Pipe()

    // Intercept STDOUT with outputPipe
    dup2(self.outputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, FileHandle.standardOutput.fileDescriptor)
    
    outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.NSFileHandleDataAvailable, object: outputPipe.fileHandleForReading , queue: nil) {
      notification in
      
      let output = self.outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.availableData
      let outputString = String(data: output, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""
      
      DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let previousOutput = self.outputText.string
        let nextOutput = previousOutput + outputString
        self.outputText.string = nextOutput
        
        let range = NSRange(location:nextOutput.count,length:0)
        self.outputText.scrollRangeToVisible(range)
      })
      
      self.outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to change existing code, you can;

1 - redirect the output of print to a known file.
     see instructions here;  [How to redirect the nslog output to file instead of console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184235/how-to-redirect-the-nslog-output-to-file-instead-of-console) ( answer 4, redirecting)

2 - monitor the file for changes and read them in to display in your textView.

Comment: HI I have manage to implement this code in swift but my other NSLogs or in swift is print is not registering to my text file

Answer (score 0):

You can totally do that! Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13303081/1491675

Basically you create an output file and pipe the stderr output to that file. Then to display in your textView, just read the file and populate your textView.