# iOS Swift : routing NSLog calls to file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoalumberjack

is it possible to route all the NSLog calls from our iOS app and private frameworks into a single file easily.

Like redefining NSLog to something else ?

Comment: I found an answer but written in objective C. It reopens `stderr` as a file. The same technique will work in Swift. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184235/how-to-redirect-the-nslog-output-to-file-instead-of-console

Comment: I initially closed the question, but then changed my mind because there's still some work needed to translate the code to Swift.

Answer (score 0):

I translated [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5938021/13302448) to Swift for you. Call this function in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in AppDelegate.

```
func redirectConsoleLogToDocumentFolder() {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).map(\.path)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        let logPath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("console.log").path
        freopen(logPath, "a+", stderr)
    }
```

This is the path to the `console.log` file on iOS devices:   `/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/<your-app>/Documents/console.log`